# Emulating mobile browsers on Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have to emulate mobile devices on my *rspec* + *capybara* test environment.
I have read about capability of resizing windows and setting user-agents in chrome, but it's not what I need (every browser works differently:  resolution and user-agents aren't only difference between it).
I need to emulate behavior of mobile devices in 100% (if is it possible).

For example on *mobile chrome* some of my components work properly and breaks in *iOS safari*, this is why I want to write tests to mobile devices that check all browser each.
It would be amazing if this emulator would show browsers navigation bars if is it possible.

Do you know any good technologies, emulators, gems etc. that can help me? I thought about downloading some emulators and set it as browsers in *capybara* config, but maybe it's not best idea and I haven't found any tutorials/docs how to do that. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

A few years since I had this same problem, but I used GenyMotion with Appium and xCode iOS simulator. However I had to use an old version of xCode as the later versions no longer had Safari as a default app in the emulators anymore.

No idea if this has changed recently but worth looking into.

The integration into Appium and then either GenyMotion/xCode was pretty straightforward and that was very well documented. https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/ seems to be a good start.